# Java Maven Application Downloads Working Locally But Not On Server

Tags: java, maven, download, classpath

I have a Maven/Spring/Java application where I allow the user to download a file. Here is the directory structure of my application.

```
src
  main
    java
      com
        mycompany
          controller
            MyDownloadController
    resources
      downloads
        MyDocument.docx
```

And here is the controller code that downloads the file.

```
File file = new File("src/main/resources/downloads/MyDocument.docx");

response.setContentType("application/docx");
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"MyDocument.docx\"");

DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

int length   = 0;
byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[4096];
while ((inputStream != null) && ((length = inputStream.read(byteBuffer)) != -1)) {
    outputStream.write(byteBuffer, 0, length);
}

inputStream.close();
outputStream.close();
```

Everything works fine on a local Tomcat server. But when I try to upload to a server (Jelastic), I get a 500 error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/downloads/MyDocument.docx (No such file or directory)`.

I looked in the Tomcat directory on the server and the documents are there (didn't screenshot the actual documents for company privacy).

[image: structure]

I am guessing this has something to do with classpaths or something. But I don't know what exactly I need to update or how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your file is in the resources directory, you'll need to refer to it as a classpath resource.  Resources on the classpath could be present in a directory structure or in an archive such as a jar or war.  In your case, your local environment has these files on the filesystem, but when deployed, they end up in a war.

FileInputStream is not a good choice when accessing classpath resources.

The correct way to access these files is by using a classloader.  You can call getResourceAsStream and provide the location to the resource.  In your case it will look like this:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("/downloads/MyDocument.docx")
```

This will use the classloader that was used to load the current class.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("MyDocument.docx");
```